# Using <a> tag in thymeleaf iteration

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I need to display a list of links coming through list using thymeleaf.
I was successfully able to do the same using following code:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6" th:each="ApplicationVO: ${ApplicationList}"> 
              <a class="service-link shadow" title="MMIS" href="mmis.html" target="_blank"><span th:text="${ApplicationVO.applicationName} +'&raquo'"></span></a>
          </div>
```

My question is how do i put the link(href) and title in anchor tag as ApplicationVO.applicationLink and ApplicationVO.displayName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use th:href tag:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6" th:each="ApplicationVO: ${ApplicationList}"> 
          <a class="service-link shadow" title="MMIS" th:href="@{${ApplicationVO.applicationLink}}" target="_blank"><span th:text="${ApplicationVO.applicationName} +'&raquo'"></span></a>
</div>
```

I think that you could also remove the span tag like this :

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6" th:each="ApplicationVO: ${ApplicationList}"> 
          <a class="service-link shadow" title="MMIS" th:text="${ApplicationVO.applicationName} +'&raquo'" th:href="@{${ApplicationVO.applicationLink}}" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, the th:href did'nt work, though th:text would work. making href would make it to point to http://localhost:8010/TestApp/ApplicationVO.applicationURL   and not the content of it.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot the ${} around ApplicationVO.applicationLink. I have edited the answer. Sorry for confusion.